# C++ return pointer to member

Tags: c++

What is the syntax for a return type of "pointer to a member"?

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

// compiles
decltype(&Point::x) getX () {
   return &Point::x;
}

// does not compile... how to do this without decltype?
int (Point::*) getX () {
   return &Point::x;
}


// Use case:
Point p, q;
auto pm = getX();
p.*pm = 1;  // p.x = 1
q.*pm = 2;  // q.x = 2
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a pointer to a `size_t`?

Comment: @Ranic: No. I've updated the question with a use case.

Comment: From what instance are you returning their member **x**? Or you need **x** to be static?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `size_t`? Are you trying to return a pointer to a `size_t` member of `Point`? `Point` doesn't have any.

Comment: @Brian: Oops, that was supposed to be an `int`.

Comment: @NetVipeC: Pointer to members ignore what instance they come from. They are used to dereference specific members from instances.

Comment: What button did you push to get all the page views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need parentheses there:

```
int Point::* getX () {
   return &Point::x;
}
```

---

Imagine using parentheses with a regular pointer:

```
int (*) getX() // compiler says WTF
{
   static int x; 
   return &x;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the superfluous parentheses and change the type to `int`:

```
int Point::* getX () {
   return &Point::x;
}
```

[Demo, because coliru is down at the moment](http://ideone.com/KpKND9).

Answer (score 3):

The declaration syntax (approximately) follows the usage syntax.

To use `getX`, you would write `p.*getX()` (where `p` is a `Point`), and this would produce a `int`. So the declaration is:

```
int Point::*getX()
```